Как экспортировать код с переменными из файла js в react компоненту?
Мой код (возможно этот код кривой и его нужно исправить):
  let switchMode = document.getElementById("switchMode");
  let theme = true;

  switchMode.onclick = function(theme) {
    if(theme){
      theme = false;
    }else{
      theme = true;
    }
  }

как его экспортировать, чтобы можно было вставить в реакт так, чтобы при нажатии кнопки с id = "switchMode" я мог возвращать что-то одно?
import React from 'react';

function NavBar() {
 if(DarkMode){
  return (
      Белая тема
  )
 else{
  return (
      Темная тема
  )
}}


С точки зрения Реакт, ваш код кривой и его надо выкинуть. Вместо этого написать обработчик клика внутри компонента и сохранять состояние.

И еще нужны пояснения, что подразумевается под "экспортировать код"? Сам кусок кода экспортировать не получится, а вот функции, переменные - можно(стандартный import/export). Можно обернуть нужный кусок кода в функцию и его экспортировать.
